# Binding model data to view - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot

I am not able to bind the data in the model to the view. I am using spring boot.  At the moment I got it working like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/members")
public ModelAndView getMembers() {
    List<Member> members = memberDao.getMembers();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("member/membersList");
    model.addObject("members", members);
    return model;
}
```

This let me access the model attribute using

```
<c:forEach items="${members}" var="member" varStatus="memberStatus">
  <tr>
    <td>${member.id}</td>
    <td>${member.firstName}</td>
    <td>${member.lastName}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I am trying to get it work by returning a String rather than the ModelAndView. Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/members")
public String getMembers(ModelAndView model) {
    List<Member> members = memberDao.getMembers();
    model.addObject("members", members);
    return "member/membersList";
}
```

I am not so sure about using `@ModelAttribute` on the java side or `commandName` in the jsp. Is that something I need to look at? Can someone please enlighten on what is going wrong?

Adding Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class MemberController {

@Autowired
private MemberDAO memberDao;

@RequestMapping("/members")
public ModelAndView getMembers() {
    List<Member> members = memberDao.getMembers();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("member/membersList");
    model.addObject("members", members);
    return model;
}
}
```

Comment: Show us the controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object to be rendered on `JSP` should be added as [Model](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html) attribute:

```
@RequestMapping("/members")
public String getMembers(Model model) {
    List<Member> members = memberDao.getMembers();
    model.addAttribute("members", members);
    return "member/membersList";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first way should work. If not please check if you have @taglib declaration in your JSP, for example:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

If you return String (as in your second example: "members/membersList") the Spring will try to find and show JSP page with the name of membersList.jsp inside "members" location. Parameters will not be passed to JSP in that case.